# Generate a diagram or schema that shows the relationships between all the files in a website

Tags: javascript, php, css, indexing, schema

The last 9 months, I've been working on two big websites with **PHP** and **Javascript** without using any **framework**.

Every time I wanted to modify a page or fix a bug, I was spending:

1. *10%* of the time on finding the **PHP** file with the html content
2. *20%* of the time on locating the **CSS** and **JavaScript** files it is using
3. *20%* of the time on locating the **PHP** *classes* it's using and the functions and variables it's inheriting
4. *20%* of the time on locating all the scripts that are being called through **ajax calls**.
5. And only *30%* percent of the time to actually fix the problem.

So, I wanted something that for every file that I want to modify within a project, after *indexing* all the aforementioned, it shows a list with all of these *relationships* on a *diagram/flowchart* along with the corresponding *links* to these files.

After a lot of *Googling* I couldn't find anything that directly solves this problem effectively. Right now, except for just opening all the includes inside the **PHP** file one by one, I am using **Google Chrome**'s *Inspector* to quickly locate the includes from the *Network tab* or even add my whole *Workspace* in the *Sources tab* in order to apply **CSS** and **JavaScript** modifications directly from there. The problem with this, is that I don't have any options for locating any server-side code(**PHP**). Also I don't want to be dependent on any specific *Web-Browser*. Lastly, this solution doesn't provide me any graphical representation of the website's *schema*, something that's really important for understanding in seconds the whole structure of a webpage that you are going to modify for the first time.

I know that this question sounds a little **off-topic** but I couldn't find anything on the Web (maybe I didn't use the correct search keywords?) and I feel like it's something that a lot of developers struggle with sometimes so it could be really helpful if it's answered and stay visible. Even if I am missing the point due to luck of experience and there is a different approach to this kind of problems, I don't think I am the first one and It could be also good to be clarified for all the others out there.

Comment: Have you considered using a IDE? Like PHPStorm or something? If you don't use an IDE, why?

Comment: I would prefer something that it's project specific(like a framework) rather than computer specific (like and IDE or a Web Browser). The reason for that is that I don't want to be dependent on the operating system or the  specs of the computer I am using each time.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with the **diagram** part of your question but I understand that your problem is **indexing**.

You could use **sublime** which more or less work with all the operating systems and at the same time it's quite light. With it you will have indexing as you can see [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/file-indexing).